# How to implement Redux DevTools?

Tags: redux

This is the index.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducers/reducers";

const store = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store(rootReducer)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

To be able to use Redux DevTools I need to add this line of code:

```
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
```

I tried this:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducers/reducers";

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [ReduxPromise];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store(rootReducer)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

But then I get this error: **TypeError: store is not a function**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong:

`store(rootReducer)`

You've *already* created the store, by calling `createStore(rootReducer)`.  As the error says, `store` is not a function, and you can't "call" it.  Just pass `<Provider store={store}>`.

Also, note that [our new Redux Starter Kit package](https://redux-starter-kit.js.org) can help simplify the store setup process for you.